# Returning an XElement from a web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xelement

Is it possible to return an XElement from a webservice (in C#/asp.net)?

Try a simple web service that returns an XElement:

```
[WebMethod]
public XElement DoItXElement()
{
  XElement xe = new XElement("hello",
     new XElement("message", "Hello World")
     );

  return xe;
}
```

This compiles fine but if you try and run it you get

```
Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema.
```

I found [this post implying that this is a bug](http://blog.bksanders.com/index.php/tag/linq-to-xml/) in .net.

So... Can I return an XElement from a web service?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be an issue with how an XElement is serialized, check [here](http://www.developersdex.com/csharp/message.asp?p=1111&r=6149937)...

You can try outing the XElement as a string or as the article suggests you could just use a class wrapper and place your XElement inside. If the point is to output the data in a universal format you'll be stuck with returning a string.

Comment: Being more prescriptive - it is the nature of XElement to be indeterminate until runtime. However the WebMethod needs a determinate root to begin deserialization. Wrapping is the way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately the external link is broken now.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to avoid the string!

I can return an XmlNode (created from the XElement), which gets me what I need - a slug of XML on the client.  Thanks for that link - I shall investigate the XWrapper further...

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, it seems that this only happens if you are trying to look at the "Discovery" part of the service - You can run the method without a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Return an XmlElement type, and just use this extension method to convert from XElement to XmlElement:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()]
public XmlElement ToXmlElement(XElement value)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(value.ToString());
    return xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
}
```

This seems to work well.