# .net webservice with XElement return type

Tags: c#, web-services

There is a way to make a webservice that returns a parameter of the type XElement?
Now I'm working with XmlNode return type, but I want to get rid of using this old xml library.

I'm using this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement xml = new XElement("produtos");
doc.Add(xml);

//...
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (var xmlReader = doc.CreateReader())
{
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
}
return xmlDoc;
```

I can't figure out why the webservice dont work with the XmlLinq lib

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning an XElement from a web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349769/returning-an-xelement-from-a-web-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public XElement GetSomething()
{
    return new XElement("Something");
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply
I tried and it I'm get an error:
System.InvalidOperationException
"Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema"
This error is ocouring just by opening the asmx page on the browser, can't even execute

Comment: I think maybe my answer was a bit misleading. You can turn your service into a ScriptService by adding this attribute above your WebService class: `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`. It will behave differently than your current service which will have a schema and SOAP responses, but it is a way to return an XElement if that's all you're trying to do.

Comment: Alternatively, you could return the string that the XElement produces, or write an extension method to convert the XElement to an XmlNode and return that instead which should work.

Comment: Thanks Ocelot20, I found the "error", I believe is a bug on .net or vs.
The webservice is running ok, it just dont work on the asmx page that is created automaticaly, and dont generate the WSDL file, but the webservice is running. I don't know why MS don't fixed it yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I used an extension method to convert the XElement to an XmlElement (per suggestion of @Ocelot20):

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function ToXmlElement(value As XElement) As XmlElement
    Dim xmlDoc = New XmlDocument()
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(value.ToString())
    Return xmlDoc.DocumentElement
End Function
```

Seems to work fine!