# Returning an XElement from a .ASMX Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I was recently updating a .ASMX Web Service in which it was returning an `XElement` and came across this error message:

[image: Cannot use wildcards at the top level of a schema]

Now this error was produced by the following code;

```
public class FooBarService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{            
    [WebMethod]
    public XElement Foo(string Bar)
    {
        return null;
    }    
}
```

However, if I change the code to accept an `XElement` rather than a `String`;

```
public class FooBarService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{        
    [WebMethod]
    public XElement Foo(XElement Bar)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then the Web Service does not throw the error.

So why does a method that accepts an XElement and returns an XElement work, but not the other method?

Comment: Related question here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349769/returning-an-xelement-from-a-web-service - seems like it might be a bug?

Comment: @ChrisMcAtackney Yeah I have read through that question, the link is broken from one of the answers, and the rest do not shed any light on the problem.

Comment: Why not return a string instead?

Comment: Because I don't want to :P I want to find out why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place to start with would be the stack trace, which indicates the place where the exception occured:

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaExporter.ExportElement(ElementAccessor accessor)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaExporter.ExportTypeMapping(XmlTypeMapping xmlTypeMapping)
at System.Web.Services.Description.MimeXmlReflector.ReflectReturn()
at System.Web.Services.Description.HttpProtocolReflector.ReflectMimeReturn()
at System.Web.Services.Description.HttpPostProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod()
```

By using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) we may observe the conditions which trigger the exception:

```
// System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaExporter
private XmlSchemaElement ExportElement(ElementAccessor accessor)
{
    if (!accessor.Mapping.IncludeInSchema && !accessor.Mapping.TypeDesc.IsRoot)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (accessor.Any && accessor.Name.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("XmlIllegalWildcard"));
    }
    // truncated method body
}
```

Navigating further into the code:

```
// System.Web.Services.Description.MimeXmlReflector
internal override bool ReflectReturn()

// System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter
private ElementAccessor 
    ImportElement(TypeModel model, 
        XmlRootAttribute root, 
        string defaultNamespace, 
        RecursionLimiter limiter)
```

and so on, we get to this method:

```
// System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter
private static ElementAccessor 
    CreateElementAccessor(TypeMapping mapping, string ns)
{
    ElementAccessor elementAccessor = new ElementAccessor();
    bool flag = mapping.TypeDesc.Kind == TypeKind.Node;
    if (!flag && mapping is SerializableMapping)
    {
        flag = ((SerializableMapping)mapping).IsAny;
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        elementAccessor.Any = true;
    }
    else
    {
        elementAccessor.Name = mapping.DefaultElementName;
        elementAccessor.Namespace = ns;
    }
    // truncated
}
```

It seems that the `XElement` type mapping gets the `Any` property value set to `true` but doesn't get a `DefaultElementName`.

A simple workaround for the problem is to create a derived class:

```
public class FooBarService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public MyXElement Foo(string bar)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
public class MyXElement : XElement
{
    public MyXElement()
        : base(XName.Get("default")) { }
}
```

Which will call in the stack the:

```
System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod()
```

instead of the `HttpPostProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod()` method and the name gets assigned properly:

```
messagePart.Name = members[0].MemberName;
```

To respond to your question, the reason why the method call works when you assign the `XElement` as a parameter is because the type mapping is created through other methods and the `name` member is not empty. So the condition which raises the exception does not occur.

Comment: That is an excellent answer thanks! Also thanks for doing the investigation into this problem!

Comment: When I try to consume a service that accepts & returns MyXElement using a Web Reference in VS2010, it creates DataSet typed parameters & return type. How can you make it use XElement?